# Cannot access Isolated Storage from New Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, isolatedstorage

I have a new Silverlight Application with just a button on it that works great locally.
I deploy to my staging server and now the following code breaks:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      try
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Attempting to Access Isolated Storage");
        var store = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        MessageBox.Show("Have Storage");
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("1: Access Failed");
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
      }
    }
```

I wrote this sample app to discover what was going on in my real application. It has the same issue. My real application did work for weeks, until a few days ago. I cannot determine what is different.

Here is the Message:

```
---------------------------

---------------------------
There is not enough free space to perform the operation.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
---------------------------

---------------------------
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.Reserve(UInt64 lReserve)

   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.FetchOrCreateStore(String groupName, String storeName, IsolatedStorageFile isf)

   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStore(String group, String id)

   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()

   at SilverlightApplication1.MainPage..ctor()
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is NOTHING is the isolated storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you gave the answer yourself in the post: "There is not enough free space to perform the operation." Try to increase the size of the IsolatedStorage:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.increasequotato(v=vs.95).aspx

Also you might want to clean up the IsolatedStorage after usage. Maybe thatswhy your application worked for some days and then suddenly it broke. I guess the IsolatedStorage is just "full". Try this at the end of your code:

```
    var store = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    //...do storage stuff
    store.Remove  //removes the storage
```

Maybe also see here for some nice IsolatedStorage examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265154%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Hope I could help

Comment: Thanks, but this is a BRAND NEW test app. Nothing is in isolated storage. I wrote this app to debug the problem. In addition The dialog to ask for more space will not load.